# mailto link is not working in Chrome Browser (Version :18.0.1025.152 m)

Tags: html, google-chrome

mailto link is not working in Google Chrome browser (Ver:18.0.1025.152 m)

```
<a href="mailto:someone@example.com?cc=someoneelse@example.com&bcc=andsomeoneelse@example.com&subject=Summer%20Party&body=You%20are%20invited%20to%20a%20big%20summer%20party!">Send mail!</a>
```

I used the above code in ff and chrome. It works fine in ff but not in chrome
And you can test [this link](http://www.w3schools.com/Html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_mailto2) also. I think it is problem with chrome settings. Anyone know how to change settings?

Comment: It is working. Do you have a mail client?

Comment: It works in my Chrome, same built version.

Comment: It's working for me. Are you sure you haven't disabled chrome from opening mail links? Does it work with a simple email? (without all the cc's)

Comment: The `mailto` in your example isn't working for me with the error "Refused to display document because display forbidden by X-Frame-Options."

Comment: @Bakudan - Did you use the w3schools url... Its not working in chorme(The popup is not comming). Please advise me.. Thanks

Comment: Is it just the w3schools example not working or is your code not working properly? I have tried both of them and they are working as they should on my Chrome which is the exact same build as yours.

Comment: @Raeki - Please use above w3schools link. Thanks

Comment: @sarcastyx - this is my site link http://impulseinfo.com , There you can see at footer part of the site "contact@impulseinfo.com" mail id. Just Click on that.. I think it should some setting problem with my Chrome. Thanks for helping me

Comment: That link worked fine. It opened my Outlook Mail without any problem. It does sound like a setting issue with your Chrome.

Comment: @sarcastyx - Thanks for the help. Do u have any idea about setting issue. And please make sure that your chrome version is 18.0.1025.152 m, Because my friends have the same issue. Thanks once again

Comment: @Kushal, looks like your default mail program for Chrome has been changed. I haven't been able to find any easy way of doing that. The best I can do is point you to Google.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9945/discussion-between-kushal-and-sarcastyx)

Answer (score 7):

This is because chrome handles the mailto in different way. You can got to `chrome://settings/handlers` and make sure that which is the default handler. In your case it will be none. Now go to gmail.com. You should see something like this when you click on the button beside the bookmark button.

[image: Set mailto in chrome]

If you wish to open all email links through gmail then set use gmail. Now when you click on mailto button, chrome will automatically opens in gmail.

Comment: Please give this man a cookie. VERY IMPORTANT to check what he showed about GMail, I was going nuts trying to figure out why it didn't pop up something to prompt me what I wanted to handle that with. Nice catch sir - +1

Answer (score 6):

You can check which program is mapped to handle mailto: links by entering `chrome://settings/handlers`. It could well be that if the mailto: handler is somehow misconfigured, Chrome silently fails on mailto: links.

More information on handlers, including allowing websites to handle special links is available at http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1382847

For what it's worth, mailto: link in the W3Schools example works without problems with Chrome 19.0.1084.41 (Official Build 134854) beta-m and Outlook 2010 under Windows 7 Professional (64-bit).

Answer (score 2):

It happens because your **email default program** doesn't working correctly.

Comment: I noticed this behaviour in the default Android browser as well.

Answer (score -1):

This fixed mine .. Set your default email reader.

http://see.kirkstrobeck.com/VD7s

Answer (score -3):

It is not because of the Chrome Settings...
Chrome is more specific for the Html and CSS, so your problem is probably that one of your 's is going over the link or image if you're trying to use an image as a mailto command.
Once you are on the page you are trying to make this work right click and choose "inspect element" and check if another element is going over your link...
Then in Css fix that and your mailto link will work...

Hope this helps

website design