# MailTo with from name doesn't work in Chrome

Tags: html, email, mailto

```
<a href="mailto:Nexus%20DJ%20Entertainment&lt;info@nexusdj.co.uk&gt;">info@nexusdj.co.uk</a>
```

doesn't work in Chrome, but works in all other main browsers including mobile safari.

Any ideas?

Comment: It doesn't open your mail client? If yes, what are you using? Maybe this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10099711/mailto-link-is-not-working-in-chorme-browserbrowser-version-18-0-1025-152-m) will help you

Comment: @ton1c as you can now see my HTML code, you can see that it is only when the email is given a name that chrome doesn't open in Apple Mail.

Answer (score 1):

It is working in chrome  26.0.1410.43

You can also try

```
<form action="mailto:info@nexusdj.co.uk" method="post">
    <input type="submit" name="mailSend" value="Contact Me" />
</form>
```

Comment: A bare email address works, but when giving the email a name, it doesn't work. Thanks for help though :)

Comment: It is working, check this fiddle jsfiddle.net/chepe263/cRF9s My email client is thunderbird. Maybe Apple Mail and Chrome dont get along

Comment: Do you thing there's some javascript error in the console giving you trouble?

Comment: I know, but that doesn't help my visitors when they click on it and nothing happens!

Answer (score 1):

I've been trying to figure out how to fix this problem for quite a while, and after reading through the specification a few times I believe I've figured it out.

According to the specs, `<a href='mailto:"Heckofa guy" <chart@chartlive.com>'>` is not a valid mailto link, it can only be a plain email address.  I guess all the browsers except chrome just decided to make it work anyway, even though it's technically invalid.

Luckily the specs pointed at the answer, which is specifying the `to` header instead of listing an email address.

According to my testing this works fine(only tried FF and Chrome as I'm on a Mac):

```
<a href='mailto:?to="Heckofa guy" <bob@bobby.com>'>not using to</a>
```

Here's the spec, just for reference:
http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2368.txt

My testing code:

```
<a href="mailto:&quot;Heckofa guy&quot;%20&lt;bob@bobby.com&gt;">with name</a> Doesn't work.<br>
<a href='mailto:"Heckofa guy" <bob@bobby.com>'>with name no encoding</a> Doesn't work.<br>
<a href="mailto:bob@bobby.com">without name</a> Works.<br>
<a href='mailto:?to="Heckofa guy" <bob@bobby.com>'>not using to</a> works?!?!?<br>
```

Here's a jsfiddle showing it in action:
http://jsfiddle.net/kmkvP/

Comment: After further research it seems that I was wrong, You can specify a name in the normal way, but chrome on the mac(only on mac) seems to be very picky about encoding.  Everything must be fully percent encoded.

here's another fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kmkvP/1/

Answer (score -4):

Without seeing your HTML tag, I can't help you much here, apart from showing that standard syntax is:

```
<a href="mailto:<email address>" > LINK BODY </a>
```

Perhaps chrome does an assertion that the email address is valid before executing the mailto window? A google-exclusive optimization would explain why it only fails on chrome and not the others.

Comment: I think his tag is fine. It's working in all other browsers. So the problem must be with Chrome configuration not calling the email client